# Text Overlay on Images in a Grid Upon Mouse Hover

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a grid set up correctly but can't quite figure out how to do so. I'd like to get it into a 2x2 with a text overlay and change of opacity over each image when the mouse hovers over the image. I'm using the skeleton CSS framework.

JSFiddle(for my CSS scroll down to the bottom): https://jsfiddle.net/w758bg0s/1/

Here is the code I have written:

HTML:

```
<div id="specials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h2>This season's specials:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one-half column">
          <div class="food-image food1">
            <img src="http://z.lmnd3.com.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/07/24/20/05/30/422/White_Nectarine_Persian_Cucumbers_English_Peas_Watercress.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-half column">
          <div class="food-image food2">
            <img src="http://z.lmnd3.com.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/07/24/20/07/10/934/Spaghetti_Squash_Almonds_Balsamic.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one-half column">
        <div class="food-image food3">
            <img src="http://z.lmnd3.com.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/07/24/20/08/21/750/Southwest_Panzanella_Pickled_Nopales_Jicama_Corn_Tortilla.jpg">
              <div class="img-descrip">
                  <p>Southwest “Panzanella,” Pickled Nopales, Jicama, Corn Tortilla</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-half column">
          <div class="food-image food4">
            <img src="http://z.lmnd3.com.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/07/24/20/09/24/865/Roasted_Carrots_Sunchokes_Avocado_Almonds.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Specials
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
#specials{
  background-image: url(http://i.lmnd3.com/images/LemonadeBkg_Avoc.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 800px;
}
#specials h2{
  margin-top: 10rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#specials .food-image{

  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 250px;

}
#specials img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#specials .img-descrip{

  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

All the best -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#specials .img-descrip {
    color: #000;
    margin-top: -5em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#specials img {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
}

#specials .food-image:hover img{
   opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. One more question though, would it be possible to force all four images to be the same size? The bottom right seems a bit smaller than the rest.